# Is defining class variables as null required if they are going to be set during construct?

Tags: php

let say we have class Person($name), Does $name need to be asigned as null as such:

```
class Person{
    var $name = null;

    public function __construct($name = null){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Or can var $name = null be eliminated all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely leave it as `var $name;`. `null` will be the default value anyway.

Comment: Technically speaking, `null` is actually the absence of a value. +1 Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not do `var $name = null;` and you try to access it before it is assigned you will get warnings/errors.

But in your case I do not see why it is needed, except for readability of the code (although you can add a comment about it)

Comment: Strictly speaking you'd get a `warning` and not an error wouldn't you?

Comment: Well, you can do `var $name;` (or better yet, `public $name;`) only and that'll do. It is `null` by default anyway. So no, the `null` is not necessary because it's implicit: since null is basically nothing, a property with no value is null.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to declare the properties beforehand for documentation and IDEs' auto-complete functionality.  However, it's not something that's required by PHP.

Also, unless you are worried about PHP4 (I hope not), it's more proper to use "public" instead of "var".